# How is an 8gb USB drive transformed into a 250mb drive?

Tags: hard-drive, usb

I have a USB data traveler 8gb thumb drive.  I have used it in the past and it hads 8gb of space like it says.  I eventually erased everything from the drive and installed a USB version of google chrome OS just to test it out, after I did that I erased the drive again. ever ince then the drive is completed erased/formated butno matter what I do, even with the drive appearing empty, it still says that it is now a 250mb drive instead of an 8gb drive.   This is really frustrating as I cannot install anything on it larger then 250mb even though it should have 8gb of space.  I am using it on Windows 7.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  I have tried formatting is several times with no success in getting it to register as an 8gb drive instead of a 250mb drive.

Comment: sounds like my dilemma http://superuser.com/questions/173281/reusing-a-usb-boot-drive-format-back-to-factory-state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try re-partitioning the USB drive.

https://superuser.com/questions/173293/partition-a-usb-drive-on-windows

Comment: Thank you, I tried that "Lexar USB Format" program and that seemed to restore it to it's full capacity

Comment: your link is broken, the question's been deleted